# Add a keyboard shortcut to bookmark a post

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a keyboard shortcut to bookmark a post?  And if there isn't, could we add one?

I bookmark posts very frequently (on Stack Exchange, not in my browser), enough so that I would really appreciate a keyboard shortcut to be able to do that.  I have looked all through the options in <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>?</kbd>, and there doesn't seem to be a shortcut.

There are shortcuts to vote, to see the timeline of a post; could we add one more keyboard shortcut in that area?

Comment: Based on a glance through the script, there does not appear to be one.

Comment: I would love this, tbh. Perhaps a shortcut to upvote and downvote a post as well? Shift U and Shift D would do the trick :)

Comment: @10Repisn'tactiveonMSE There is already.

Comment: @10Repisn'tactiveonMSE To vote:  Shift+?, click V for Vote, click U or D.