# Add keyboard shortcut for editing the list of duplicates

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, keyboard-shortcuts, dupehammer

Users with a gold badge in a tag are able to edit the list of duplicates for a question. There are no keyboard shortcuts defined for this. For example, a rather routine task is to close a question against multiple duplicates, yet the workflow can be cumbersome:

1. Go to the question and press <kbd>M</kbd> (**m**oderate) -> <kbd>C</kbd> (**c**lose) -> search for the first duplicate -> <kbd>Enter</kbd> (close as duplicate).
2. Use the mouse to click Edit in the duplicate notification.
   [image: Notification area for duplicate closure. There is an "Edit" button on the top right.]
3. Use the mouse to click "Add".

   [image: Page with a list of duplicates. There is a "Remove" button for each duplicate, "Add" and "Save" buttons for the list.]
4. Search for a duplicate and add it.
5. Use the mouse to select "Save".

Steps 2. and 3. and 5. can be achieved much easier with keyboard shortcuts.

---

Only a few are needed:

- On a closed question

  - Shortcut for editing the duplicate list. This could be under "moderate".
- On the page for the duplicate links

  - Adding a duplicate.
  - Saving the list.
  - Selecting a duplicate. <kbd>J</kbd> and <kbd>K</kbd> are used to select next/previous post, so it could be consistent to keep those. But there can be other alternatives.
  - Removing a selected duplicate.
  - Moving a selected duplicate up or down. This is not essential but it is a functionality of the page. Not having it keyboard accessible is not much of a loss, though.